# Using jQuery method chaining to initialize TypeScript static property results in TS2448: Block-scoped variable used before its declaration

Tags: typescript

I upgraded an existing project from TypeScript 2.1.6 to 2.2.1 tonight and started getting `TS2448` errors that I'm having a tough time understanding.

Here's a minimal example:

```js
// Environment Summary:  Visual Studio Code 1.9.1 with the following installed:
//
//    > npm list
//    test@0.0.1 C:\Users\abrown\src\test
//    +-- @types/jquery@2.0.40
//    +-- jquery@3.1.1
//    `-- typescript@2.2.1
//
namespace TestNamespace {
    export class TestClass {
        // Contrived, just to support showing a minimal example:
        private static getTemplate(): JQuery { return $(document); }

        // TypeScript error:
        // test.ts(7,53): error TS2448: Block-scoped variable 'find' used before its declaration.
        private static jq = TestClass.getTemplate().find("whatever");

        // But OK here:
        private static test() {
            var jq = TestClass.getTemplate().find("whatever");
        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what it is about the initialization of my static property that makes it illegal TypeScript.

Both `TestClass.getTemplate()` and `JQuery.find()` return a value of type `JQuery`.  If I strip the chained call to `.find()` from the line where I'm initializing `jq`, it compiles without error.  I can't see what it is about adding the chained call to `.find()` makes it illegal in the context of static property initialization.

Finally, I'll quickly note that with the jQuery type definitions in place, I get Intellisense/auto-completion on the call to `.find()` that causes the compiler error.

Comment: File an issue at TypeScript. :) I think this is a regression.

You can validate by looking at the compiled code.

Maybe the static methods are declared in the reversed order.

Comment: I have filed [issue 14312](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14312) with the TypeScript team.  I will update this question after any feedback is received from that defect report.

Comment: I get this same error for `public static onSomething = $.Callbacks();` - but not sure if it's for the same reason